# Fastest way to disable a specific date in my current datepicker code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This code is mainly to extend the functionality of a plugin and as such it's coded slightly differently.
What's the fastest way around restricting a date from getting selected?  i.e. 2021-02-25

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){
        jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker("destroy");
        jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker({
            minDate: 3,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                return [(date.getDay() != 1)];
        }
        }).attr('readonly','readonly');
    });
</script>
```

I have tried the below code but this is obviously wrong, I would appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){
        jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker("destroy");
        jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker({
            minDate: 3,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                return [(date.getDay() != 1 && date != "2021-02-11")];
        }
        }).attr('readonly','readonly');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var unavailableDates = ['11-2-2021', '25-2-2021'];

  function unavailable(date) {
    if(date.getDay() == 1){
      return [false, '', 'Unavailable'];
    }
    dmy =
      date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
      return [true, ''];
    } else {
      return [false, '', 'Unavailable'];
    }
  }

  jQuery(document).on('ready', function () {
    jQuery('.checkout-date-picker').datepicker('destroy');
    jQuery('.checkout-date-picker')
      .datepicker({
        minDate: 3,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
      })
      .attr('readonly', 'readonly');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: with this code, my datepicker no longer pops up on selection, also - what about the mondays that i m trying to block as well? thanks for the input!

Comment: @user3448267 I have edited my comment for Mondays. Please check the console and check if you have any errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var noCheckOut = [
    "2021-02-11"
  ];
  var dtFormat = "yy-mm-dd";

  function exceptions(date) {
    var results = [true, "", ""];
    var ftDate = $.datepicker.formatDate(dtFormat, date);
    if (date.getDay() == 1 || noCheckOut.indexOf(ftDate) >= 0) {
      results = [false, "exception no-check-out"];
    }
    return results;
  };
  $(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker("destroy");
  $(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: dtFormat,
    minDate: 3,
    beforeShowDay: exceptions
  }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Check Out: <input type="text" class="checkout-date-picker"></p>
```

Please see:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay
- https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

> **$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, options )**

> Format a date into a string value with a specified format.